# Query ordering in SQL Server within sub number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of datatype `varchar`, when I normally select like this

```
column
------
1
2
3
4Answer
4
5
1_1Answer
1_2Answer
2Answer
6
7
8
10Answer
9
10
```

I want result ordering by number and sub number like this

```
column
-----
1
1_1Answer
1_2Answer
2
2Answer
3
4
4Answer
5
6
7
8
9
10
10Answer
```

I have a lot of data like that, more than 20 within sub number

Comment: normalize your data. this is the ideal solution.

Comment: i guess `partition by over (column where column like %Answer% ` is required to add these subgroups to existing groups is required

Comment: @Gordon's answer should address your immediate concerns. Sadly, @ scsimon's comment is the best path--to sort first by number and then by (optional) character addenda, the data should be stored as separate columns using the appropriate datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example data you listed, you can use the query

```
--Create example table to use
CREATE TABLE #Test ([Column] VarChar(50))

--Add example data to the example table
INSERT INTO #Test([Column]) VALUES
('1'),
('2'),
('3'),
('4Answer'),
('4'),
('5'),
('1_1Answer'),
('1_2Answer'),
('2Answer'),
('6'),
('7'),
('8'),
('10Answer'),
('9'),
('10')

--Select data from the table, ordering by the number part at the beginning of the column, and then by the whole column
SELECT [Column]
  FROM #Test
  ORDER BY
    CASE 
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[_a-z]%', [Column]) = 0 THEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, [Column]) 
    ELSE TRY_CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Column], PATINDEX('%[_a-z]%', [Column]) -1))
  END,
  [Column]
```

Comment: **thx :)**   CASE 
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[_a-z]%', [nomor_pertanyaan]) = 0 THEN CAST(nomor_pertanyaan AS INT) 
    ELSE CAST(LEFT([nomor_pertanyaan], PATINDEX('%[_a-z]%', [nomor_pertanyaan]) -1) AS INT)
  END,

Answer (score 3):

This is called 'natural sorting' and most databases don't support this by default.

In my case, i wrote stored procedure in postgres for hsndling this. I don't know which is your db software; google 'natsort' for it

update: got to the PC. Here is what i'm using in postgres (partially found here, on stackowerflow):

```
      /* Split the input text into contiguous chunks where no numbers appear,
      and contiguous chunks of only numbers. For the numbers, add leading
      zeros to 20 digits, so we can use one text array, but sort the   
      numbers as if they were big integers.                               

        For example, human_sort('Run 12 Miles') gives                     
             ['Run ', '00000000000000000012', ' Miles']
   */                                                                     
   select array_agg(                                                     
     case                                                                 
       when a.match_array[1]::text is not null                            
         then a.match_array[1]::text                                      
       else lpad(a.match_array[2]::text, 20::int, '0'::text)::text        
     end::text)                                                           
     from (                                                               
       select regexp_matches(                                             
         case when $1 = '' then null else $1 end, E'(\\D+)|(\\d+)', 'g'   
       ) AS match_array                                                   
     ) AS a
```

Usage: `select ..... order by natsort(field)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have only one subnumber, you can convert the leading digits-plus-underscore to a decimal value and use that in `order by`:

```
order by convert(decimal(10, 4),
                 replace(left(column,
                              patindex('%[^0-9_]%', column + 'x') - 1
                             ), '_', '.'
                        )
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if i had messed it up the below query but gave a try. What I meant by this below query is all the columns of single digit/word as groups while the others as subgroups.

```
      Select column over
               (Partition by 
             column where column 
         like '%Answer%' ) from 
        table group by column  order by 
          column;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use oracle you could do like this:

```
order by substr(your_column, 1, 1) asc
```